# Delete all *mp3 files without confirmation and inside all folders /sub

Tags: rm

I am now in the **"upload"** folder (centos 7)

I want the files ***mp3** which is inside this folder and the folders inside it
without being constantly **"y"** Hit

I use this code, but I have to go into each folder and run the code, which is time-consuming . I want all to be deleted automatically.

```
rm *.mp3
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and at least tell us what operating system you are using. Do you ave `GNU` tools? Is this Linux, Unix, MacOS, BSD, something else? What shell are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use GNU `find` for this. If you are already in the target directory:

```
find . -name '*.mp3' -delete
```

That will find all files whose name ends with `mp3` in this directory and all sub directories and delete them.

Comment: I tested this, it didn't delete at all

Comment: @amirsalarr then run `find . -name '*mp3'` and look at the output. Are the files there? Maybe you are not in the right directory?

Comment: @amirsalarr what command did you run? Did you perhaps forget to quote `'*.mp3'`?

Comment: @amirsalarr are you sure that the files left over end in `mp3` and not things like `wav` or `MP3`?

Comment: Thank you, it worked